# How to make Rank ignore a cell base on its value

Tags: google-sheets

I hope someone can help me with this. Basically, what I'm trying to do is rank the column "C" but in a way that it will only count if the student has a score of higher than 10 in "column B" . If not, then it will be skipped from the rank. I dont know if this is possible.

Trying to make it like this one in the link. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJL02.jpg

I tried searching for it and tried several formulas but it wont work. Im hopeless in this program.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming ColumnC has a header and is sorted descending, this may help:

```
=iferror(match(C2,query(A:C,"select C where B>10"),0),"")
```